# Estimating Object Speed Opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I have been doing a bit of research lately and I found out that in-order to do speed estimation with a non Calibrated camera one has to know distance between some objects in the scene, in my case I am trying to estimate speed of cars, in my country the white markings on the road are `3m` in length and the gap between them is `4.5m`, from what I read I could simply measure the time it takes for the vehicle to complete the given length, how to calculate the book never explained, so I thought of something like

if we take `Point carCentroid` as my vehicle centroid and `Point roadMarkStarting`, `roadMarkingEnding` as my road mark, where `roadMarkStarting`, is the point and the start of the marking and `roadMarkingEnding` is at the end of my marking, we could basically check when the vehicle's centroid is at starting point and start measuring time it takes to reach the ending point, then do all sorts of calculation on the data to obtain the speed, I like this method because I can easily measure speed of many objects which were not taken by me, basically because no Camera calibration is needed, but the issue is when I trying checking `if(carCentroid.y == roadMarkingStarting.y)` nothing happens, it seems they are never on the same line, is there a way I could put a range to day if `carCentroid.y` is within `4px` from startingPoint accept it as well? this is what I thought would work for speed estimation, anyone who has done speed estimation in Opencv on non Calibrated camera please help on how you did it

Comment: As far as "if `carCentroid.y` is within 4px from startingPoint", just change your if statement to something like `if (carCentroid.y > roadMarkingStarting.y - 4 && carCentroid.y < roadMarkingStarting.y + 4)`. Not the most elegant, but it will do. I am not sure if Java has any `Range` class, but if so that would be the approach to take for readability sake.

Comment: thanks alot, I already solved it.